# Read app.config file in Installscript

Tags: installshield-2008

I wan to know that how to read connection string from app.config using installshield es, though there is an option to import the app.config file XML structure but the problem is the section of the connection is being updated at runtime.

During Upgrade i need to fetch the the app.config file's connection string section is there any way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: I guys finally i found the option to read the app.config file section, hope this might help you. Using FileGrep(svtargetFile, svSearchText) you can Serach the given text(svSearchText) in given file config(svtargetFile) & return Line No. in while loop